# Clear data in Excel using SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have created s Stored Procedure in SQL which imports data from a flat file, updates the data and imports the updated data within a table.

After some research, I found that the only way to export this (64bit) table would be to create a SSIS package and use a SQL Job to execute the package.

I have done all of this and managed to get the table data exported but the problem is that it does not clear the data before the import. I have then created the following

[image: SSIS Package]

When dropping the excel table, I have the following SQL Statement : DROP TABLE [Sheet1$]
When creating the table, I have the following SQL Statement :

`CREATE TABLE 'Sheet1$' 
(
    BRANCH NVARCHAR(10) ,
    SRCBRANCH NVARCHAR(10) ,
    DEPARTMENT NVARCHAR(10) ,
    GLCODE NVARCHAR(10) ,
    DOCDATE NVARCHAR(10) ,
    VALUE NVARCHAR(50) ,
    ITEMREFERENCE NVARCHAR(100) ,
    MISCREFERENCE NVARCHAR(100) ,
    SUFFIX NVARCHAR(10) ,
    NARRATIVE [NVARCHAR(100) 
)
GO`

After the table has been dropped, it clears all the data together with the header and then fails on the second SQL Task (Create Excel Table) with the following error message:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "CREATE TABLE 'Sheet1$' (
    BRANCH NVARCHAR(10) ,
    S..." failed with the following error: "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

After fail, I cant execute the package due to a validation error. This is because my headers in the Excel sheet has been deleted.

Could someone please point me in the right direction. I have exhausted all options.

Regards

Comment: You need to clear the table contents right? Did you try to use TRUNCATE option instead of dropping?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an error in your workflow.
You should TRUNCATE the table **before** executing the SP to import the data, not after.

Comment: Hi shree.pat18, I have updated the script to  TRUNCATE TABLE [Sheet1$]  but still get an error message :  [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "TRUNCATE TABLE [Sheet1$]" failed with the following error: "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Hi grahamj42, the table I export from SQL gets truncated within the SP. The excel spreadsheet (which will always have data in) should then be deleted leaving the headers. When I executed the SSIS package before trying to clear all data from spreadsheet it worked fine except the data would be concatenated together with the previous data. After dropping the table within Excel, all I want to do then is re-import the data which is done in the Data Flow Task.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand! How about using a file system task to copy an excel file with just the header to the desired location and then exporting the data into the newly-initialised file.

Comment: would `DELETE * FROM [Sheet1$]` work instead of dropping and re-creating the table?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE 'Sheet1$' 
(
    BRANCH NVARCHAR(10) ,
    SRCBRANCH NVARCHAR(10) ,
    DEPARTMENT NVARCHAR(10) ,
    GLCODE NVARCHAR(10) ,
    DOCDATE NVARCHAR(10) ,
    VALUE NVARCHAR(50) ,
    ITEMREFERENCE NVARCHAR(100) ,
    MISCREFERENCE NVARCHAR(100) ,
    SUFFIX NVARCHAR(10) ,
    NARRATIVE **[**NVARCHAR(100) 
)
GO
```

***This is your syntax error. This was asked quite a while ago so I would think you have rectified this by now but I wanted to post for others to know what the issue was.